# Radial and transverse components of velocity and acceleration.

Tags: vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Find (i) the velocity $\dot r(t)$, (ii) the speed $\Vert \dot r(t)\Vert$, (iii) the acceleration $\ddot r(t)$, (iv) the radial and
>   transverse componentes of velocity and acceleration at $t$, of a
>   particle whose motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is described by:
>
> 1. $r(t)=(a\cos (t^2), a\sin(t^2), t\in\mathbb{R}$
> 2. $r(t)=(a\cos\omega t, b\sin\omega t), t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\omega$ constant.
> 3. $r(t)=(a(1+\cos t)\cos t, a(1+\cos t)\sin t), t\in\mathbb{R}.$

This is what I did:

- $r(t)=(a\cos (t^2), a\sin(t^2), t\in\mathbb{R}$

(i) $\dot r(t)=(-a\sin(t^2)2t, a\cos(t^2)2t)$

(ii) $\Vert \dot r(t)\Vert=\sqrt{(-a\sin(t^2)2t)^2 + (a\cos(t^2)2t)^2}=\sqrt{4a^2t^2}=2at$

(iii) $\ddot r(t)=(-2a(t\cos(t^2)2t+\sin (t^2)), 2a(-t\sin(t^2)2t+\cos(t^2))=(-4at^2\cos(t^2)-2a\sin(t^2), -4at^2\sin(t^2)+2a\cos(t^2))$

- $r(t)=(a\cos\omega t, b\sin\omega t), t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\omega$ constant.

(i) $\dot r(t)=(-a\omega \sin(\omega t), b\omega\cos(\omega t))$

(ii) $\Vert \dot r(t)\Vert=\sqrt{(-a\omega \sin(\omega t))^2 + (b\omega\cos(\omega t))^2}=\omega\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(\omega t)+b^2\cos^2(\omega t)}$

(iii) $\ddot r(t)=(-a\omega^2\cos(\omega t), -b\omega^2\sin(\omega t))$

- $r(t)=(a(1+\cos t)\cos t, a(1+\cos t)\sin t), t\in\mathbb{R}.$

(i) $\dot r(t)=(-a\sin t-2a\sin t\cos t, a\cos t+ a\cos^2 t-a\sin^2 t)$

(ii) $\Vert \dot r(t)\Vert=\sqrt{a^2+2a^2\sin^2\cos t+2a^2\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t+a^2\cos^4 t+ a^2\sin^4 t+2a^2\cos^3 t}$

(iii) $\ddot r(t)=(-a\cos t+2a\sin^2 t-2a\cos^2 t, -a\sin t-4a\cos t\sin t)$

Am I correct? How do I calculate the radial and transverse components of the velocity and the acceleration? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I did not check the math for the last case, but the first two are correct. In order to find the radial and transverse components, you must use the scalar product. Define $$\hat r(t)=\frac {r(t)}{|r(t)|}$$
Then the radial component of a vector $v$ is $$v_r=(v\cdot\hat r(t))\hat r(t)$$
If you care only about the magnitude $$|v_r|=v\cdot\hat r(t)$$
For the transverse component, we use the fact that $$v=v_r+v_t$$
Therefore $$v_t=v-(v\cdot\hat r(t))\hat r(t)$$
So take the case of velocity in the first part:
$$\dot r(t)=(-2at\sin t^2,2at\cos t^2)$$
You have $$\hat r(t)=(\cos t^2,\sin t^2)$$
Then $$|\dot r_r(t)|=-2at\sin t^2\cos t^2+2at\cos t^2\sin t^2=0$$
It means that the speed is all transverse, with no radial component. This is not surprising, since the first case is movement along a circle.

Comment: So I just have to use those two formulas in order to find the radial and transverse components? How would it be in the case of acceleration?

Comment: Exactly the same for acceleration. Just use the formula for acceleration in $v$

Comment: What's the formula for acceleration? The second derivative?

Comment: Yes. I see that you already computed that: "(iii) the acceleration $\ddot r(t)$"

Comment: So the changes I will have to do would be $a_r=(a\cdot\hat r(t))\hat r(t)$, $a=a_r+a_t$ and $a_t=a-(a\cdot\hat r(t))\hat r(t)$, right?

Comment: Correct. Just a lot of calculations. At the end of the day it's just decomposing any vector $v$ into two components.

Comment: Ok. $\hat r(t)$ is the unit vector, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90825/discussion-between-andrei-and-davidllerenav).